# Windows Backup to network share (Server 2008)

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, backup, share

I'm trying to setup Windows Backup on a Server 2008 machine to backup to a network share. When I run the wizard to setup the backup I get an error message:

> The user name being used for accessing the remote share folder is not recognized by the local computer

I have no idea what this means. Any help?

The server with the network share is a domain controller (also server 2008). 
The server I am trying to back up is not and is not part of the domain.

Answer (score 6):

Make a user account on your backup server that is a copy (username and password) of a valid user account on the domain and use that to run the backups

Comment: correct answer!

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I'm trying to backup a WinSrv2019 (NOT joined) to a WinSrv2016 machine (joined) and it doesn't allow me to create the backup to the network share.