# Unjoined hyper-v host backup

Tags: active-directory, backup, windows-server-2012, hyper-v, local-area-network

We have just added a WinSrv2019 Hyper-V host running two virtual machines (one Domain Controller 2019 and one MS Exchange 2016) without joining the host to the company domain.

We need to back up this host but all the network shares are not accessible despite [this trick](https://serverfault.com/a/112364/38557).

The questions are:

1. Should we purchase an external NAS for this purpose?
2. Does another *safe* way to backup to a network share exist?
3. Are there other options we are not considering?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the network shares hosted on one of the VM's? If so, you're creating a difficult dependency if the host crashes and needs to be restored to bare metal.

Purchase a suitably sized external USB drive and connect it to the host. Backup the host to this external USB drive.

Comment: No, network shares are on the real machines joined to the domain. I already did this test with an old external USB HD and it was so slow. Do you think that a modern USB 3.0 would perform significantly better? The server supports USB 3.0 as specified here: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/81759/intel-c612-chipset.html

Comment: Currently, we have a RAID 10 disk configuration, is there the option to add a single HD dedicated to backup? These are the machine specs: https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/povw/poweredge-r430